# C# WinForms: populating datagridview with datasource from two different tables

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

When I have to populate a dgv with only 1 table it's ok, I know how to do it (List< Entity > coming from database to datasource). But when I have a table that has a FK with another one, I don't know how to show another property of that table (and not the ID, that the user wont understand). I think what I've done with LINQ is really bad (BTW I'm new to LINQ, I don't know if I need it, at least here). The problem with my solution comes when I try to get the selected ID from the DGV.

```
private void LoadDGV()
    {
        BuildingLogic oBuildingLogic;
        try
        {
            oBuildingLogic = new BuildingLogic();
            SocietyLogic oSocietyLogic = new SocietyLogic();
            List<Building> listBuildings = oBuildingLogic.GetAll();
            List<Society> listSocieties = oSocietyLogic.GetAll();


            this.dgvBuildings.DataSource = (from building in listBuildings
                                            join society in listSocieties
                                            on building.IDSociety equals society.ID
                                            select new { building.ID, FullName = building.FullName, ShortName = building.ShortName, Society = society.Name, Date = building.Date, City = building.City, Address = building.Adress }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            oBuildingLogic = null;
        }
    }

    private int ItemSelectedID()
    {
        if (this.dgvBuildings.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            //something like this?
            //this.dgvBuildings.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvBuildings.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't show the ID in the dgv, I only need it to identify the dgv row with the database row. dgvBuildings.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem returns me an anonymous type, the ID is there, I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Both return the same ID value, am I right ? The classic way for you is create a class to hold your data then it won't be anonymous type anymore

Comment: What I did was make ID a column of my dgv and Visible:false. so I can select it with this
    return Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvBuildings.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);

Comment: Yep, I always let the DGV auto generate columns, hide some columns that I use to manage data from user and use a function to prepare the DGV's look like column width, align... by its data type.